# In Putty I want to save the settings to reflect all the sessions

Tags: linux, putty

I want to specify the layout, no. of columns, no. of rows... all these configurations should be transferred to the remaining sessions too.

How can I do this?.

I'm very new to putty, so I don't know where to find everything yet. So please explain the steps how to do this as well!

Answer (score 2):

[image: change screen size setting][image: save the current setting into a profile/session]

After you make the necessary changes, you can save that session for next time usage

Comment: How do I save the session @Ajreal?

Comment: @Ivo Flipse - click on the `Session`, fill-up in the session name, etc...and click `save`

Comment: Hehe @Ajreal, I was hoping that you would add it to your answer ;-) Always tempting people to make awesome answers!

Comment: @Ivo Flipse - lazy to screen capture again ...

Answer (score 2):

Save as the "Default" session to make it the default settings. Select the "Session" category on the left, then enter "Default" for session name, and click on "Save" button.

If you want just to change the settings of a session, you can (in same place as mentioned above) first load the session, then change settings, then save again.

Comment: How would I have to do that @Maxelost?

Comment: Select the "Session" category on the left, then enter "Default" for session name, and click on "Save" button.

Comment: If you want just to change the settings of a session, you can (in same place as mentioned above) first load the session, then change settings, then save again.

Comment: Could you add this to your answer?